# Sanbox app for android

Tags: gratis, android, sandbox

Need suggestions for some good sandbox apps for Android.
I want to install an app and test it, but it's picking up some credentials automatically. So thought of having a sandbox app that could prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (in theory) simply use Android's work profile, but AFAIK that's not directly accessible without some MDM stuff. You could also simply create a separate user (or profile), but that would mean constantly "switching around". So back to your original request:

There are indeed some [Sandbox apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_1141)¹ – I'd recommend looking first at **[Shelter](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.typeblog.shelter/)** and **[Insular](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.oasisfeng.island.fdroid/),** as these two are available from F-Droid and thus you can be pretty sure they carry no trackers etc. themselves. Both not only let you isolate apps in sandboxes, but also freeze them into inactivity to make sure they're not running without you having explicitly asked them to.

¹ <sub>disclosure: link goes to my Android website</sub>